# Is it Mandatory to have same Name ( Word-to-Word) on all your Identity Documents ( India)?

Tags: india

I have an issue with my PAN and Aadhar Card with both having Either Initial or Full Middle name difference. My Question Specifically is , when Government of India has taken pains to maintain Biometric and Eye Scans , specifically to provide each and every individual a seperate identity ,

1. Why do some government Organisation ( Like UAN ) mandate the name to be Exactly same ? ( Word to Word )
2. **Is it illegal** to have different names with minor difference ( e.g 1st letter of middle name on one PAN Card and Full Middle Name in Aadhar Card )
3. Why cant Organisation verify persons identity using e-aadhar or Biometric rather than Matching names  ?
4. Is there an Indian Penal Code who do not follow rules to verify Aadhar using government guidelines ?

Comment: For a country with such a large population, it would seem that matching names is a particularly poor way of identifying people.  But law frequently lags behind technology, and I expect this to be no different.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me that using a middle initial v. a full middle name is a different name, even in a strict literal sense. A better example would be someone like my mother who sometimes used her middle initial ("A") in her name and sometimes used the first letter of her maiden name ("B") in her name instead. FWIW, in Colorado there is case law and a title standard to the effect that middle names in legal documents don't count.

Comment: It shouldnt count , for e.g  Peter S. Martin or Peter Steve Martin , both are one and the same individuals , and if only its creating a confusion to government , they are additionally capturing Mobile No. , Biometric and Eye Scan so they have 3 Unique ways to identify Individuals Identity. Still of many other Organisations do not have such modern systems to verify , there should be a law governing this.